# 5.1.7 Hera - Wi-fi internet connection problem

Tags: release-hera, networking

There was a problem with the Wi-Fi connection. Every 5-10 seconds I get a notification that the network was disconnected. After 1-2 seconds connection returns.

[image]

On the Live USB and Windows, the problem does not occur. I suppose a problem with some broken package, but I have no idea where to find the source of the problem.